# How to properly send a file with additional variables in a Django HTTP response?

Tags: django, response, httpresponse

I know how to return a JSON response:

```
return Response({'example':'example'})
```

and also know how to return a file response:

```
response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
return response
```

But if I want to send both in one response, how can I **properly** do that? [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields) gives an example for setting additional header fields:

```
>>> response = HttpResponse()
>>> response['Age'] = 120
```

But from reading a couple [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339906/sending-data-via-request-header-vs-sending-data-via-request-body) I've seen, it looks like sending business data in headers it not the way to go. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking with `Content-Disposition` there are two options:

- Put the additional data in the headers.
- Store the meta-information in the value, e.g. `attachment; key=value; filename="my.txt"`.

Comment: The first sentence is seemingly contradictory to the second: you can pass data in the headers.

Comment: So I think there really are two options if you want to send file + data in one response. First, put the data in headers. Second, make a normal json response and encode the file as json. I am trying to figure out which is better

Comment: @bones225 I would start to think differently. Is there really a need to pass the additional data along the file downloading? Maybe it's a good idea to use the second endpoint, though it depends on a particular case.

Comment: I think I might split my api into a second endpoint in that case. Or maybe I'll just put the variables in the headers.